# Custom object-to-string mapper in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Using AutoMapper (v6.2.2, plus *AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection*) I want to use my existing system `TypeConverter` classes to convert from certain data models to strings.

Although the internal `MapperRegistry` contains a `TypeConverterMapper` that should be able to do this automatically (*without the need for any manual configuration* it says [here](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html)), it never gets called as the `StringMapper` takes precedence when the destination type is a `string`.

Other (older) answers suggest changing the mapping objects in the `MapperRegistry`, but it appears that this class has since been made `internal`.

Can I change the precedence of (or remove) the different in-built mapper classes in AutoMapper?

---

As a workaround, I also tried creating a map in my `Profile` that would attempt to convert any object to a string using type converters:

```
private class ApiTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<object, string>
{
     public string Convert(object source, string destination, ResolutionContext context)
     {
        TypeConverter sourceTypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(source.GetType());
        if (sourceTypeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(string)))
        {
           return (string)sourceTypeConverter.ConvertTo(source, typeof(string));
        }

        return default(string);
     }
}
```

which I configured to be used with:

```
CreateMap<object, string>().ConvertUsing<ApiTypeConverter>();
```

But this has not worked as expected yet either. Ideally I'd only do this for members which could be converted using a condition, something like:

```
ForAllMaps((m, e) => e.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(HasConverter))
                      .ConvertUsing<ApiTypeConverter>());
```

However, this is not possible (the `ForAllMembers` method returns `void`).

---

As I am using *AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection* I was able to use the `additionalInitAction` parameter to change the mappers:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(InitAction, GetType().Assembly);

private void InitAction(IMapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
{
    var mapper = configuration.Mappers.OfType<StringMapper>().First();
    configuration.Mappers.Remove(mapper);
}
```

This led everything to work as expected, but seems a bit of a hack, as other maps may be relying on the `StringMapper`.

Comment: I've added an example, but maybe you should spend some time reading the docs. A type converter doesn't work that way. It only matches by types. Maybe you want a resolver.

Comment: You get more flexibility then a map with [a simple object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/5e17750d1eebb9f286e2d53489d24bd304d63fdf/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L92) or you can go even further with ForAllPropertyMaps and a resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `configuration.Mappers` to change the built-in mappers' list, but a map from object to string should also work.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    var mappers = cfg.Mappers;
});
```

Comment: Where do I get `configuration` from? I only found `Mapper.Configuration.GetMappers()` which I cannot change.

Comment: Upgrade. Or find a similar thing in your particular version.

Comment: Went with adding a custom object mapper to the mappers collection, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If using dependency injection, the configuration can be changed when adding the AutoMapper to the services:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(InitializeMapper, typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

Then add an appropriate initialization:

```
private static void InitializeMapper(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
{
    StringMapper stringMapper = cfg.Mappers.OfType<StringMapper>().First();
    int index = cfg.Mappers.IndexOf(stringMapper);

    cfg.Mappers.Insert(index, new CustomObjectMapper());
}
```